# Mouse scroll - snap to divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a page in the form of

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="content-page-1">
    <!--content-->
    </div>
    <div id="content-page-2">
    <!--content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make scrolling either

1. Stick/snap to divs (these are 100% height and 100% width of the display area)
2. Auto-scroll to next div when scrolling detected

with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you listen for the scroll event on your node, you could easily use a plugin like [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) to smooth scroll to the "next div" or previous div (however you define that).

```
var prevScrollTop = 0;
var $scrollDiv    = $('div#content');
var $currentDiv   = $scrollDiv.children('div:first-child');
$scrollDiv.scroll(function(eventObj)
{
    var curScrollTop = $scrollDiv.scrollTop();
    if (prevScrollTop < curScrollTop)
    {
    // Scrolling down:
        $currentDiv = $currentDiv.next().scrollTo();
    }
    else if (prevScrollTop > curScrollTop)
    {
    // Scrolling up:
        $currentDiv = $currentDiv.prev().scrollTo(); 
    }
    prevScrollTop = curScrollTop;
});
```

Comment: Nice!
This works very well when I add the scrollto functions :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried different plugins but they all had problem with multiple event firing in mvc, so i came up with this solution using underscore.js

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            var isc = _.throttle(function (event) {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
                    if (event.handled !== true) {
                        $.post('@path', function (html) {
                            $('#user-feed').append(html);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, 300);

            $(window).scroll(isc);
    });

</script>
```